# Join tables using Jakarta Criteria

Tags: criteriabuilder

I'm trying to do some joins between tables using criteria, but I'm getting the following error:

`org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Attribute [com.amfpromotora.entity.EmprestimosTabelas#tabcodigo(BASIC)] is not joinable`

I know that to make the join work, I need to insert the @JoinColumn annotation in my entity, but in this case the foreign key is in the target tables.

Here is the relationship between the tables in my select

```
FROM emprestimos_tabelas t
    JOIN emprestimos_bancos b ON t.banccodigo = b.banccodigo
    JOIN emprestimos_comiss_agenciador c ON t.tabcodigo = c.tabcodigo
    JOIN emprestimos_comiss_correspondente cc ON c.tabcodigo = cc.tabcodigo AND c.parmin = cc.parmin
```

Entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "emprestimos_tabelas", schema = "public", catalog = "joinconsig")
@Data
public class EmprestimosTabelas {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "tabcodigo")
    private int tabcodigo;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "banccodigo")
    private EmprestimosBancos banccodigo;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "tabnome")
    private String tabnome;
    
    ...
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "emprestimos_comiss_agenciador", schema = "public", catalog = "joinconsig")
@IdClass(EmprestimosComissAgenciadorPK.class)
@Data
public class EmprestimosComissAgenciador {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tabcodigo")
    private EmprestimosTabelas tabcodigo;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "parmin")
    private int parmin;
    ...
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "emprestimos_comiss_correspondente", schema = "public", catalog = "joinconsig")
@IdClass(EmprestimosComissCorrespondentePK.class)
@Data
public class EmprestimosComissCorrespondente {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "tabcodigo")
    private int tabcodigo;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "parmin")
    private int parmin;
    ...
}
```

And here is my attempt at joins using CriteriaBuilder.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<CommissionTable> query = cb.createQuery(CommissionTable.class);
    Root<EmprestimosTabelas> root = query.from(EmprestimosTabelas.class);

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    Join<EmprestimosTabelas, EmprestimosBancos> bancosJoin = root.join("banccodigo");
    Join<EmprestimosComissAgenciador, EmprestimosTabelas> comissAgenciadorJoin = root.join("tabcodigo");
    Join<EmprestimosComissAgenciador, EmprestimosComissCorrespondente> comissCorrespondenteJoin = comissAgenciadorJoin.join("tabcodigo");
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, if someone can help me, I appreciate it.